# how to add an image source inside href in code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm developing a asp.net website.I have a xml file.
it has a structur lie :

```
  <Image Header="AboutUS">
<Imagepath>guest.jpg</Imagepath>
<imagetitle>welcomeguest</imagetitle>
```

i have to read this data and display this in a asp.net page:
My code look like this.

```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/multipleimage.xml"));
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("Image");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
           HtmlAnchor a1 = new HtmlAnchor(); 
            Image imagesource = new Image();                
            string path = "Uploads/";
            string imageurl = path + node.SelectSingleNode("Imagepath").InnerText;             
            imagesource.Height = 95;
            imagesource.Width = 95;               

            Div1.Controls.Add(imagesource);
```

now i want to use light box effect for this images.but i dont know how to give ahref for image from code behind...

Need help...

Answer (score 0):

hey i found the answer :

```
          HtmlAnchor a1 = new HtmlAnchor(); 
            Image imagesource = new Image();                
            string path = "Uploads/";
            string imageurl = path + node.SelectSingleNode("Imagepath").InnerText;

            imagesource.ImageUrl = imageurl;
            imagesource.Height = 95;
            imagesource.Width = 95;                
            a1.Attributes.Add("href", imageurl);
            a1.Controls.Add(imagesource);
            Div1.Controls.Add(a1);
```